# Scrollable JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jdesktoppane

I'd like to add scrolling capability to a `javax.swing.JDesktopPane`. But wrapping in a `javax.swing.JScrollPane` does not produce the desired behavior.

[Searching the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=scrollable+jdesktoppane) shows that this has been an issue for quite some time. There are [some](http://jscroll.sourceforge.net) [solutions](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1130-jscroll.html) out there, but they seem to be pretty old, and I'm not not completely satisfied with them.

What **actively maintained** solutions do you know?

Answer (score 8):

I've used [JavaWorld's solution](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1130-jscroll.html) by creating my own `JScrollableDesktopPane.`

Comment: That's actually my current solution too, but I'm not thrilled with it. I decided to ask here before embarking on my own project to create one that I like.

Answer (score 4):

Javaworld's `JScrollableDesktopPane` is no longer available on their website. I managed to scrounge up some copies of it but none of them work.

A simple solution I've derived can be achieved doing something like the following. It's not the prettiest but it certainly works better than the default behavior.

```java
public class Window extends Frame {
    JScrollPane scrollContainer = new JScrollPane();
    JDesktopPane mainWorkingPane = new JDesktopPane();

    public Window() {
        scrollContainer.setViewportView(mainWorkingPane);

        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
                revalidateDesktopPane();
            }
        });
    }

    private void revalidateDesktopPane() {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(0,0);
        Component[] com = mainWorkingPane.getComponents();
        for (int i=0 ; i<com.length ; i++) {
            int w = (int) dim.getWidth()+com[i].getWidth();
            int h = (int) dim.getHeight()+com[i].getHeight();
            dim.setSize(new Dimension(w,h));
        }
        mainWorkingPane.setPreferredSize(dim);
        mainWorkingPane.revalidate();
        revalidate();
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

The idea being to wrap `JDesktopPane` in a `JScrollPane`, add a resize listener on the main Frame and then evaluate the contents of the `JDesktopPane` on resize (or adding new elements).

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: I needed to tweak the dimension calculations and add the listener to other component events but this code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1130-jscroll.html?page=1

It's a nice tutorial with lots of explanations and infos on Swing & so, which permits to create a JscrollableDesktopPane with lots of stuff.

You will need to modify a bit some parts of code to fulfill your requirements.

Enjoy !

Comment: Oops, forgetting the direct link to the source : http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jscroll/jw-1130-jscroll.jar